# How to insert a A3 PDF into a A4 Latex document with PDFLatex?

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

Assume I have a A3 landscape PDF, how can I include this into a A4 portrait latex document but still as A3-page?

If I have `one.tex` producing a landscape A3:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{center}   
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{figure} 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

After creating one.pdf with pdflatex, I can insert this into a A4 portrait document `two.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]\clearpage
\includepdf[pages=1,noautoscale]{one}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

However, this does not work (pdflatex, TexLive '15) because this one.pdf is inserted as A4 portrait where the A3 is center clipped.

I am looking for the easiest solution (least invasive for my existing class/document).

Is it possible to get this working?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need the fitpaper option instead of noautoscale

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]\clearpage
\includepdf[pages=1,fitpaper]{one}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank this was the option I was looking for. This did the trick.. Top.  Thanks